# How to store Parse data through a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uibutton

Okay, so I am just now beginning my coding journey. I've been teaching myself for about a month now.

So I'm building this shopping app, and I have a VC that displays the details of a TVC. In this DVC, I have a UIButton (Tag) that allows that current user to favorite the product, or save the product for later review

Here is my code:

@IBAction func tagProductButton(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    var favoritePost = PFObject(className: "Tag")
    favoritePost["tagger"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    favoritePost["productId"] = 
    favoritePost["userTagged"] =
    favoritePost.saveInBackground()

}
```

I'm just trying to figure out how I can add the "productId" of the current product getting tagged, as well as the user of that product "userTagged" to display the data in Parse - so they can receive the notification.

My "productId" column is pointing to my Product class of course. & my "userTagged" column is pointing to my User class of course.

Someone please help me out!
Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the question you are asking.. but the sender argument in the function is in fact the button that 'sent' the click event.
You could subclass UIButton into a class called ProductButton, where you attach a variable on it that will hold an ID to the the product in the cell.

This question is a bit ambiguous to me, I hope this helped get you on the right path :).

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ProductButton : UIButton {

   var productId : String?


   override func touchesBegan(....) {
       super.touchesBegan(...)
       //query for the product class using PFQuery and assign the product here
       productId = findProductIdFromQuery()

   }
}
```

This could maybe something close to the answer you are looking for...

```
@IBAction func tagProductButton(sender: ProductButton) {

    var favoritePost = PFObject(className: "Tag")

    favoritePost["tagger"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    favoritePost["productId"] = sender.productId? 
    favoritePost["userTagged"] = sender.tag 
    favoritePost.saveInBackground()

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. Basically, when a user clicks on this "Tag" button under a specific product item, I want to save the action in Parse. I have a class named "Tag". I want to store the productId and the user of the product in the class so that I can send a notification to the user whose product has been tagged. But I am not sure how to retrieve the productId or the User that posted the product.